# Set AuthComponent when doing a manual login with AJAX

Tags: ajax, cakephp, cookies, authentication

Using CakePHP 2.0, when logging in the normal way, a helpful set of cookies is set and accessible via AuthComponent::user(). However, this does not get set when doing it the AJAX way. The verification works fine, but I would like to figure out how to set AuthComponent without a hard refresh.

Maybe I could do without AuthComponent and just store cookies, but I wanted to check to see if there's an easy way to do this before doing all of that work.

I've checked the JsHelper and Authentication pages in the CakePHP 2.0 documentation.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Matthew Morrone, can you give at least one example of what cookies you're trying to access with `AuthComponent::user()` Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a function in the user around the lines of:

```
public function autologin() {
        $this->autoRender = false;
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
          if ($this->Auth->login()) {
           $cuser = $this->Auth->user();
           $this->Session->write('Udata', $udata);
           $fD = array('loggedIn'=>true,'vdata'=>$udata);
          } else {
           $fD = array('loggedIn'=>false,'vdata'=>'Your username/password combination was incorrect');
          }
          echo json_encode($fD);
        }
}
```

and call this page with your ajax. with the JSON run some check;